# herausstechen aus der Masse

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, vocabulary

> Sie stechen persönlich aus der Masse heraus.

Wer kann mir sagen, wie ich diesen deutschen Satz noch anders formulieren könnte?

Comment: "Sie fallen auf", denn ein wenig ausführlicher, was gesucht ist, würde enorm weiter helfen und sich besser hier in die Liste gut gestellter und motivierter Fragen einreihen.

Comment: »Wer von euch weiß, wie ...« ist eine typische Floskel, die Lehrer verwenden, wenn Sie Schüler im Unterricht befragen, um herauszufinden, ob sie das verstanden haben, was sie gelernt haben. Wenn man diese Floskel anwendet, kennt man selbst sie Antwort und will wissen, ob andere ebenfalls die Antwort kennen. Wenn man hingegen die Antwort selbst nicht kennt, und sie in Erfahrung bringen möchte, ist diese Floskel fehl am Platz. Ich habe deine Frage entsprechend editiert und dabei noch andere Fehler korrigiert.

Comment: Danke Herr Schölnast ! Das war sehr nett von Ihnen.

Answer (score 1):

> *Sie stechen persönlich aus der Masse heraus.*
> Wer kann mir sagen, wie ich diesen deutschen Satz noch anders formulieren könnte?

Das kommt darauf an, was genau ausgedrückt werden soll:

#### Masse

"Masse" ist ein zumindest problematisches Konzept, wenn es um (Gruppen von) Menschen geht. Wie genau ist "Masse" definiert, bzw., welche Definition soll denn zugrundeliegen? Alle Menschen? Alle Rechtshänder? Alle eingewanderten schwarzhaarigen Transsexuellen mit Vorliebe für Currywurst? Wenn man - zum Beispiel - ein exzellenter Schachspieler ist, dann hebt man sich nicht "von der Masse" ab, sondern insbesondere von den anderen - weniger guten - Schachspielern.

"Masse" als Bezeichnung für Gruppen von Menschen wird - meiner Erfahrung nach - üblicherweise verwendet, wenn es etwas zu verbergen oder zu verdrehen gilt: wenn einem was nicht paßt, dann wird nicht gesagt "mir paßt das nicht", sondern dann wird die "schweigende Mehrheit", "die Masse" oder dergleichen mehr für sich reklamiert: "*Ganz Deutschland stöhnt über ....*" - das ist, wie etwa das deutsche Zentralorgan für Gift und Galle (Bild) Meinung macht. Mit den bekannten Konsequenzen...

#### "persönlich"

"persönlich" ist der nächste problematische Begriff. Was genau soll das heißen? Was ist zB der exakte Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen diesen beiden Sätzen:

> Sie stechen persönlich aus der Masse heraus.
> Sie stechen aus der Masse heraus.

Es steht natürlich *dem einen wie dem anderen, in dieser Beziehung sind wir alle gleich, mehr oder weniger* frei *sich in welcher Form auch immer auf irgendeine beliebige Art und Weise buchstäblich oder im übertragenen Sinn* bedeutungsloser Füllphrasen zu bedienen. Guter Stil ist das nicht. Wenn das Wort "persönlich" also eine Bedeutung haben sollte, die sich mir nicht erschließt, dann wäre "persönlich" durch etwas zu ersetzen, was sich mir erschließen kann. Wenn es hingegen *keine* Bedeutung hat, dann kann man es genausogut auch weglassen, oder?

**Also**: zuerst sollte genau festgelegt werden, *was* man eigentlich sagen will. Das ist der (auch in anderen Antworten und Kommentaren hier angemahnte) Kontext. Sobald das geklärt ist, kann man Vorschläge machen, wie man das am besten ausdrückt - aber vermutlich wird Dir dann auch selbst eine passende Formulierung einfallen.

Nicht umsonst sagt Wittgenstein in seinem *Tractatus*: "Alles, was gesagt werden kann, kann klar gesagt werden." Das Schwierige beim Schreiben ist ja nicht, Worte zu finden, sondern, sich zuerst einmal der Bedeutung klar zu werden, die diese Worte haben sollen. Wenn erst das "*was will ich sagen?*" geklärt ist, ist das "*wie drücke ichs aus?*" üblicherweise simpel.

Comment: So wahr, insbesondere der letzte Absatz.

Answer (score 0):

Das »persönlich« würde ich weglassen, wenn der Kontext nicht dagegen spricht (was wahrscheinlich ist).

Eine Alternative wäre:

> Sie heben sich von der Masse ab.